# Importing .jar file directly via filepath at runtime

Tags: java, linux, import-libraries

This is a "out of curiosity" question. I'm familiar with setting up user libraries in IDEs (NetBeans, Eclipse) and importing them to programs via something like

```
import com.mongodb;
```

Is there a way to import a jar file for a library directly though? Something like

```
import C:/lib/mongodb/mongo-java-driver-2.12.2.jar;
```

or perhaps

```
import /libs/mongodb/;    // for linux, where /libs/ is a softlink
```

Again, this is a mere curiosity. I understand that this goes against most conventions, but I'm looking at rapidly developing prototypes in the future and I was wondering if this is a viable option for saving some time in the development cycle.

Comment: don't see what time you are trying to save?  you can't write an import statement directly to a file, but you can add any jars you want to the java command line.

Comment: This is not possible. What would be the benefit? There are multiple problems with that. 1) This is a fixed path, it only works either on windows or linux 2) the user can't replace the implementation with a different implementation (unless he renames the jar) 3) You are fixed on a version 4) You would still need to import the classes, e.g. `import com.mongodb.Query;`

Comment: thanks for the quick answers. The idea would be to not type out the import on the command line every time I wanted to compile and run

Comment: @Kyte than you should take a look into build scripts/environments like maven, ant, gradle, buildr, ivy, and maybe Makefiles.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind, this is definitely what I will do in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is, that you only import packages in Java, not whole JAR files. 
*(Actually you can also import static class members, using `import static` but that's a different topic)*.

If you really need, you can just import the all classes from a package using the simple notation like:

```
import com.mongodb.*; // This will import all classes from "com.mongodb" package
```

And then execute your application like this:

```
java.exe -cp "your-awesome-app.jar;lib/*"
```

where `lib/*` means *"import everything"* from the `lib` folder that lies next to `your-awesome-app.jar`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/219801/1344008) on how to use wildcards with `-cp` parameter.

Comment: this is what I'm going with for now.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do exactly like that, with the weird syntax and all, but a [custom classloader](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/geronimo/xbean/trunk/xbean-classloader/src/main/java/org/apache/xbean/classloader/JarFileClassLoader.java?view=markup) can load jar-files at run time. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime) question.